# tvOS change destination when press Menu button

Tags: swift, tvos

Let's say I have 3 `ViewControllers` **A**, **B** and **C**.

**A** has a segue to **B**, and if I'm at **B**, I can just press Menu Button to return to **A**.

**B** has a segue to **C**, but when I'm at **C**, I DON'T want the user to return to **B** through Menu Button, but I want him to go to **A** instead (that is, if he is at **C**, if he press Menu Button, he should go to **A**).

How can I do this? I'm using `Swift`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

Suppose these are functions on ViewController C.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("MenuPressed"))
    tapRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UIPressType.menu.rawValue)]
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


func MenuPressed(){
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "C_to_A", sender: nil)
}
```

if there is a Segue from C to A with identifier "C_to_A", then if the user press Menu (from C), he will be taken to A (instead of B).

Comment: Presumably the "C_to_A" segue needs to be some kind of unwind rather than a normal segue that would create a new copy of "A".